# shinydashboard some Font Awesome Icons Not Working

Tags: r, shiny, font-awesome, shinydashboard

When using `shinydashboard` I find that some icons seem to work while some don't. In the below example, the battery-full icon doesn't work while the clock-o icon works fine. I'm unable to figure out why this should happen.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Some Icons Not Working?")

# No sidebar --------------------------------------------------------------

sm <- sidebarMenu(

  sm <- sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(
      text="asdf",
      tabName="asdfasdf",
      icon=icon("battery-full")),
    menuItem(
      text="qwer",
      tabName="qwerqwer",
      icon=icon("clock-o"))
  )
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sm)

# Compose dashboard body --------------------------------------------------

body <- dashboardBody(

  tabItems(

  )
)

# Setup Shiny app UI components -------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin="black")

# Setup Shiny app back-end components -------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {


}

# Render Shiny app --------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try using ion icons from this version: https://ionic.io/ionicons/v2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, I think the new ones in version 4.4 are not updated. You can probably request `shiny` team to update them and they will do it very easily. Alternatively you can do it yourself by downloading them and replacing the previous content...

**1.** Go to the [Font Awesome download page](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and get it
[image]

**2.** Locate your *font awesome* folder where you installed `shiny` package. This should be somewhere like here `~\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\shiny\www\shared\font-awesome`

**3.** Replace the content of this folder with new contents (you can delete the previous content if you want). Below is what I put in there
[image]

**4.** Now your app should work fine with new fonts
[image]

Comment: Note: I don't think this solution works for the latest version of fa https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1966

Comment: Well, the ticket is from 3 years go. A lot has changed

Comment: Any other way to fix this problem?

Comment: You can ping the guys from shiny on github and ask them to release it into the dev version https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues

Comment: some reasons it might not have worked are some differences in how to link to old and new fa-library, here is a code-example to haev both fontawesome 5 and 4 in shiny 1.2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464295/shiny-downgrade-fontawesome-5-to-4

Comment: @PorkChop I'm using the pro version of fa. Your solution works very well for me locally, but not when I deploy my app to shinyapps.io. (note that I did include my pro `font-awesome` directory inside the `www` folder of my app). Seems like there is no way to tell the [icon()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shiny/versions/1.2.0/topics/icon) function to look at the local version of font-awesome

Comment: @PorkChop I asked a question regarding my comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163719/r-shiny-wow-to-use-fontawesome-pro-version-with-the-icon-function

Comment: @PorkChop since a lot has changed with fontawesome since 2018, it would be nice to update this answer.

Answer (score 15):

This is an older question, but the issue remains for me in July 2020.  I found the solution in the [github issues page](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1966).  The trick is to make sure you are looking at the library of icons in the version of Font Awesome Shiny is calling.  Currently (again, July 2020) the version is 4.7.  [All of these icons](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/) currently work.

Another option is to call the version of fontawesome you want using the following code within your app's ui function (this solution originally posted [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/change-fontawesome-version/24727)):

```
tags$style("@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css);")
```

Answer (score 15):

For those newcomers in 2021, this **icon ... does not exist error** is due to the Font Awesome changing names to their icons between 4 and 5 (see [background here](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome/issues/2930071)). Below are solutions that do not require tag styles.

If you are getting this error message,

This Font Awesome icon ('{youriconname}') does not exist:

* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`

then, you can either:

1. **Embrace the change** and rename your icon, looking at the library, [link to 5.1.5 for example](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons), to find a new name for your match. In my case it was changing icon('dashboard') to icon('tachometer-alt'). Search with your old name, and look at the free, not grayed out, icons for an alternative.
2. Use this **useful workaround** by @samssann from `shinydashboard` [issue 373](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/373):

   1. add `verify_fa = FALSE` argument to `shiny::icon()`
   2. use `shiny::icon("clock")` or `fontawesome::fa("clock")`

P.S. You might find the icon *still shows on your app* despite the error as there is a shim to plug 4 to 5. See [@jcheng's answer](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1966#issuecomment-422544115) here from shiny issue #1966.

Answer (score 5):

Now that shiny::icon is powered by the fontawesome r package, you can use fontawesome:::fa_tbl to help you find the names that are expected from the function. fontawesome:::fa_version also tells you what fontawesome version is currently in the R package.

Answer (score 0):

For me, in Oct 2020, solution was adding a "s" after first "fa", as in `fa fa-caret-up` to `fas fa-caret-up` since it's the new syntax for font awesome icons.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a shiny app where I had this problem. To fix this I only install the library and all worked.

```
install.packages("fontawesome")
```

or

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/fontawesome")
```

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/rstudio/fontawesome)