# R Shiny: upgrade font-awesome

Tags: r, macos, shiny, font-awesome

How can font-awesome be upgraded for shiny on a mac?

Here it is for windows

[shinydashboard some Font Awesome Icons Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686195/shinydashboard-some-font-awesome-icons-not-working)

However I couldn't find any folders resembling the windows solution on the mac.

Answer (score 1):

Answer thanks to Laz Peterson, Paravis, LLC

Download font-awesome and replace the files here:

> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/shiny/www/shared/font-awesome