# This Font Awesome icon ('gears') does not exist in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, font-awesome

I faced a weird situation today, I was developing an app on R Shiny for some days and which was working on my laptop. Today I changed my PC (installed new windows) when I run my app it gave me this error:

```
This Font Awesome icon ('gears') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
Error in widgetUserBox(title = "Alexander Pierce", subtitle = "Founder & CEO",  : 
  could not find function "widgetUserBox"
```

I check back it works well on my old laptop. I tried to install and follow
[Solution mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686195/shinydashboard-some-font-awesome-icons-not-working), but nothing works. I also looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237103/r-shiny-upgrade-font-awesome). Nothing works in my case. Kindly suggest help on the latest updated package from shiny, shinydashboard.

For reference I tried to run example code which is giving same error:

```
widgetUserBox(
                          title = "Alexander Pierce",
                          subtitle = "Founder & CEO",
                          type = NULL,
                          src = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg",
                          color = "aqua-active",
                          closable = TRUE,
                          "Some text here!",
                          footer = "The footer here!"
                        ),
```

Comment: Check the `packageVersion` of the libraries related to font awesome on both the laptops. I think this might be a version issue.

Comment: PackageVersion: shiny :1.7.0,shinydashboard:0.7.1, sinydashboardplus:2.03

Comment: Looks like `shinydashboardplus` changed the function name to `userBox()` in 2.0.0 as a breaking change:   https://github.com/RinteRface/shinydashboardPlus/blob/master/NEWS.md

Comment: Finally, i was able to solve this issue by downgrading `packageVersion`

Comment: `require (devtools)`
`install_version("shinydashboardPlus", version="0.7.5",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

Comment: how does one check what version of the font awesome library is required? My inclination would be to go to: `?icon` but there is no information there apart from providing links to websites that contain lots of button names that 'do not exist' according to shiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem is just to downgrade the new version of ShinydashboardPlus from 2.0.3 to 0.7.5.

Here is the code :

```
require (devtools) 
install_version("shinydashboardPlus", version="0.7.5",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: why would you downgrade shinydashboardPlus? It may lose some other functionality. Does the `erify_fa = FALSE` not work?

Comment: @LazarusThurston, where to add `verify_fa = FALSE`? Thanks

Comment: I missed your comment @Wang. I discovered the verify_fa = FALSE also does not work. This issue is still persisting. Unsolved. Let Nirbhay revert please.

Comment: I dint tried `verify_fa = FALSE`, if its works, that will be great. My task was completed by above solution. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here it was enough to change icon names according https://fontawesome.com/v5.15 like

```
> icon("dashboard")
This Font Awesome icon ('dashboard') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE
```

will be

```
icon("tachometer-alt")
```

or `gears` to `cogs`

Comment: fontawesome.com/v5.15  link does not work, use: https://fontawesome.com/v5

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
icon = icon("play-circle")
```

use:

```
icon = icon("play-circle", verify_fa = FALSE)
```

for each icon you use.