# shinydashboardPlusGallery() example does not work

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

I have installed the R package `shinydashboardPlus` following the instructions on the official GitHub page in the Demo Section: https://github.com/RinteRface/shinydashboardPlus

As instructed I installed and loaded the package as well as the package dependencies. Then tried to run the demo dashboard of shinydashboardPlus using the command `>shinydashboardPlusGallery()` in R Studio which failed and gave me errors.

I then went above and beyond and installed and loaded several of the packages just to be sure but it still does not work.

Below is my code:

```
install.packages("pacman")
# List all the packages to be used below.
pacman::p_load(shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardPlus, styler, shinyAce, shinyWidgets, shinyjqui, shinyEffects)

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
shinydashboardPlusGallery()
```

The error I received is as follows:

```
> shinydashboardPlusGallery()
This Font Awesome icon ('fa fa-angle-down') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
This Font Awesome icon ('gears') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
This Font Awesome icon ('clock-o') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
This Font Awesome icon ('clock-o') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
This Font Awesome icon ('clock-o') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
This Font Awesome icon ('clock-o') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
This Font Awesome icon ('gears') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
This Font Awesome icon ('clock-o') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
This Font Awesome icon ('clock-o') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
This Font Awesome icon ('clock-o') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
This Font Awesome icon ('clock-o') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`
Error in dashboardPage(md = FALSE, dashboardHeader(fixed = TRUE, title = tagList(span(class = "logo-lg",  : 
  unused arguments (md = FALSE, controlbar = dashboardControlbar(skin = "dark", controlbarMenu(controlbarItem(title = "Tab 1", icon = icon("desktop"), active = TRUE, sliderInput(inputId = "inputsidebar1", label = "Number of observations:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500)), controlbarItem(icon = icon("paint-brush"), title = "Tab 2", numericInput(inputId = "inputsidebar2", label = "Observations:", value = 10, min = 1, max = 100)))), footer = dashboardFooter(left = "By Divad Nojnarg", right = "Zurich, 2019"))
```

I am using a Windows 11 OS. My R and R Studio version are as follows:

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

RStudio 2022.02.3+492 "Prairie Trillium" Release (1db809b8323ba0a87c148d16eb84efe39a8e7785, 2022-05-20) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
```

I would really like to use the shinydashboardPlus package for building my dashboards but can't seem to get started with it.

Comment: You need to change the version of your `ShinyDashboard`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69432843/8659747

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This Font Awesome icon ('gears') does not exist in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430064/this-font-awesome-icon-gears-does-not-exist-in-r-shiny)

Comment: @Kitswas thank for your response really appreciate it. I wanted to use shinydashboardPlus 2.0 and all its features. The difference between the version 2.0 any previous one is it is code breaking. Is there a way to make this work for shinydashboardPlus version 2.0. Thanks!

Comment: shinydashboardPlus 2.0 is not compatible with code written before 2.0.

Comment: @Iz100 How can I get shinydashboardPlus 2.0 to work. It does not appear to work, even just on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue while trying to access the library's demo gallery. This is clearly a problem of namespaces between the `shinydashboard` and `shinydashboardPlus` packages. If you execute the following line `search()`:

```
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"                 "package:shinyEffects"       "package:styler"            
 [4] "package:shinyAce"           "package:shinyWidgets"       "package:shinydashboard"    
 [7] "package:shinyjqui"          "package:shiny"              "package:shinydashboardPlus"
[10] "tools:rstudio"              "package:stats"              "package:graphics"          
[13] "package:grDevices"          "package:utils"              "package:datasets"          
[16] "package:methods"            "Autoloads"                  "org:r-lib"                 
[19] "package:base"
```

As you can see, in my case the `shinydashboard` package is placed before the `shinydashboardPlus` package, so in consequence the `dashboardPage` function that is being used is the one that belongs to the `shinydashboard` package instead of the `shinydashboardPlus` package.

This is a bug, and my quick solution is:

- Find where the demo app is located, you should find it in a route similar to `~\Documents\R\R-4.1.2\library\shinydashboardPlus\examples`.
- Open the `global.R` file.
- You have to change the order to assure that `shinydashboardPlus`
  package is called after `shinydashboard` package.

For instance:

```
# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyAce)
library(styler)
library(shinyEffects)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answer, I solved it with:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
shinydashboardPlusGallery()
```