# Shiny in R: Font Awesome icon ('gears') is missing

Tags: r, shiny, icons, shinydashboardplus

I got handed over a multiple-file Shiny project with custom css and the repo is a mess (I have no session info whatsoever). After fixing most bugs, I am stuck at this:

"This Font Awesome icon ('gears') does not exist"

Searching for the button, I could not find it in any of the files in the repo (CTRL + SHIFT + F yielded no results). The hosted app does not have a visible gears icon anywhere, it is however referenced in the web element "navbar sidebar-toggle" (found via Chrome dev tools). What I tried (as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430064/this-font-awesome-icon-gears-does-not-exist-in-r-shiny)):

- Re-reference it with the correct icon name: impossible as it is not actively referenced (& Font Awesome has a "gears" icon)
- Downgrading shinydashboardPlus: did not work

I am lost - any hints on how to fix an error  like that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynHMF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Usually this warning comes from the `icon()` function. Assuming you really went over ALL files in your repo (not only a subfolder but all the files from the root, like the `ui.R` if you have one), then it's really hard to tell what is prompting the warning... However, this is only what it is: a warning. Your app should function well even if you see it printed in your console. For what it's worth, I think you should dissociate the warning from the following error. Maybe try instead to search where comes the error for the missing `output` object (Maybe another Ctrl-Shift-F?). Good luck!