# Shiny apps icon with "-" in the name

Tags: r, shiny, icons, shinydashboard

I'm creating a shiny app and have come across an issue that i can't seem to find a solution to. I'm using shiny dashboard and am creating a menu system in the sideboard, and i would like to add some icons to the tabs. This works fine for all icons that does not have a - in the name, but i can't seem to figure out the once that do.

```
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("General statistics", tabName= "general_stat", icon = icon("check")),
  menuItem("Multiple regressions", tabName= "mult_reg", icon = icon("code-branch"))
)
```

The "check" icon appears but not the "code-branch". What am i doing wrong?

This may be a simple issue, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Also you can manually add them like I did for previous versions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686195/shinydashboard-some-font-awesome-icons-not-working/32689957#32689957

Answer (score 3):

It is not caused by the dash; the [`code-branch`](https://fontawesome.com/icons/code-branch?style=solid) icon is only available in Font Awesome v5.0.0, which is not used in the current release of Shiny [Shiny uses 4.7, see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=font+awesome&type=)]. As is mentioned on the linked `code-branch` page, `the code-branch` icon replaces Font Awesome 4's `code-fork`, so you could use that one for now:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("General statistics", tabName= "general_stat", icon = icon("check")),
      menuItem("Multiple regressions", tabName= "mult_reg", icon = icon("code-fork"))
    )),
  dashboardBody()


)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also you can manually add them like I did for previous versions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686195/shinydashboard-some-font-awesome-icons-not-working/32689957#32689957

Comment: That's also a nice option!