# R Shiny: how to use fontawesome pro version with the icon function?

Tags: r, shiny, font-awesome, shinyapps

I'm using fontawesome icons throughout my Shiny app via the [`icon`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/icon.html) function.

I've downloaded the pro version of fontawesome, and used the instructions here: [shinydashboard some Font Awesome Icons Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686195/shinydashboard-some-font-awesome-icons-not-working/32689957#32689957) to replace the free version that Shiny is using by default (inside `shiny\www\shared\font-awesome`) with my paying version. This works very well locally, and all the pro icons show in my app.

However, when I deploy to `shinyapps.io`, it seems like Shiny goes back to using the default version. I did try including my pro directory inside the `/www/` folder of my app, but without success. Seems like there is no way to tell the `icon()` function to look at a local version of fontawesome, something like `icon(...,lib=local)`, or `icon(...,lib=path_to_fa)`...

Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest and most reliable way to do this is to:

1. Put the font-awesome files in a subdirectory of the app, `www/fontawesome/`
2. Add the following somewhere to the UI code:

   ```
    htmlDependency(
      name = "font-awesome", version = "99.0",
      src = "./www/fontawesome",
      stylesheet = "css/all.min.css"
    )
   ```

Here's an example app that illustrates:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    "This is a Font-Awesome Pro-only icon: ", icon("acorn"),
    htmlDependency(
      name = "font-awesome", version = "99.0",
      src = "./www/fontawesome", stylesheet = "css/all.min.css"
    )
  ),
  function(input, output, session) { }
)
```

One potential issue with the other method is that if the `ui` component contains a call to `icon()`, and then there is some dynamically-rendered UI (via `renderUI()` and `uiOutput()`) which contains a call to `my_icon()` that uses an icon that's only in Font-Awesome Pro, then that Pro icon will not show up. The method I showed here will not have that problem.

Here's why the other method will have that problem: When the static `ui` for an application is rendered to HTML, it looks for `htmlDependency` objects in the `ui`, and the newest version of an `htmlDependency` for a given name (in this case "font-awesome") "wins". So if there's just a call to `icon()` in the code (and no call to `my_icon()`, or the explicit `htmlDependency()` in my example), then the htmlDependency for Font-Awesome that wins is the one that comes with Shiny, 5.13.0 as of this writing. The browser will request that version of Font-Awesome.

Later, if a `renderUI()` inserts a `my_icon()` with a Pro icon, the HTML will be sent to the browser along with an `htmlDependency` object for Font-Awesome Pro. However, at that point, the browser already has loaded Font-Awesome, and it will not know to load this newer version of it -- Shiny currently is not able to replace the already-loaded version of Font-Awesome with a newer one.

Adding the custom `htmlDependency` to the static `ui` object makes it so it can be resolved at initial page render time, and the browser knows to load the newer version from the start. The version I used, `99.0`, ensures that this custom version will "win" over any other version of a Font-Awesome `htmlDependency`.

Answer (score 7):

The trick was, inside the [`htmlDependency`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/htmltools/versions/0.3.6/topics/htmlDependency) call (in `icon()` function), to remove `package = "shiny"` and replace `"www/shared/fontawesome"` by the absolute path to my FA folder (I also updated the version number).

EDIT: to be more precise, below is the (very slightly) modified icon function:

```
my_icon = function (name, class = NULL, lib = "font-awesome") {

prefixes <- list(`font-awesome` = "fa", glyphicon = "glyphicon")
  prefix <- prefixes[[lib]]
  if (is.null(prefix)) {
    stop("Unknown font library '", lib, "' specified. Must be one of ", 
         paste0("\"", names(prefixes), "\"", collapse = ", "))
  }
  iconClass <- ""
  if (!is.null(name)) {
    prefix_class <- prefix
    #if (prefix_class == "fa" && name %in% font_awesome_brands) {
    #  prefix_class <- "fab"
    #}
    iconClass <- paste0(prefix_class, " ", prefix, "-", name)
  }
  if (!is.null(class)) 
    iconClass <- paste(iconClass, class)
  iconTag <- tags$i(class = iconClass)
  if (lib == "font-awesome") {
    htmlDependencies(iconTag) <- htmlDependency("font-awesome", 
                                                "5.7.2", "./www/shared/fontawesome/", 
                                                stylesheet = c("css/all.min.css"))
  }
  htmltools::browsable(iconTag)
}
```

Besides commenting some lines out, the only part I changed is the `htmlDependency` call. In the original function, it was:

```
htmlDependency("font-awesome", "5.3.1", "www/shared/fontawesome", package = "shiny",
               stylesheet = c("css/all.min.css", "css/v4-shims.min.css")
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the Shiny CSS to indicate that you were using Font Awesome Pro?  I followed the steps in the link you posted in your original question, plus the htmlDependency steps you describe, but only free icons are showing in my app.  I've looked at the `all.min.css` file in my Font Awesome download, and it contains the pro icons.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Nope. Are you sure you source and use the modified `icon()` function?
Did you copy the pro directory to `your_app\www\shared\fontawesome`?