# How to correctly rewrite R Shiny's function icon() to include Font-Awesome Pro icons?

Tags: r, shiny, font-awesome

This is a follow up question based on this other thread asking the same question: [R Shiny: how to use fontawesome pro version with the icon function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163719/r-shiny-how-to-use-fontawesome-pro-version-with-the-icon-function).

I tried the accepted answer, but it works only for the free icons. Other icons are not rendered, that is, nothing appears.

Here is my unsuccessful attempt at rewriting the custom `my_icon()`, "forked" from the linked thread above. My goal is to correctly account pro icons classes `fas`, `far`, `fal`, `fad`, under the assumption that `iconClass` supposed to be, for example, `fas fa-alien` (as in https://fontawesome.com/icons/alien?style=solid).

Still my change has no effect. Pro icons keep not appearing. So I must be missing something fundamental.

Note that I changed `./www/shared` into `./shared/` to avoid the warning:

> Warning: Found subdirectories of your app's www/ directory that conflict with other resource URL prefixes. Consider renaming these directories: 'www/shared'

```
my_icon = function (name, class = NULL, lib = "font-awesome") {

  prefixes <- list(`font-awesome` = "fa", glyphicon = "glyphicon")
  prefix <- prefixes[[lib]]
  if (is.null(prefix)) {
    stop("Unknown font library '", lib, "' specified. Must be one of ", 
         paste0("\"", names(prefixes), "\"", collapse = ", "))
  }
  iconClass <- ""
  if (!is.null(name) & is.null(class)) {
    prefix_class <- prefix
    iconClass <- paste0(prefix_class, " ", prefix, "-", name)
  } else if (!is.null(name) & !is.null(class)) {
    iconClass <- paste0(prefix, '-', name)
    iconClass <- paste(class, iconClass)
  }

  # print(iconClass)
  iconTag <- tags$i(class = iconClass)
  if (lib == "font-awesome") {
    htmlDependencies(iconTag) <- htmlDependency("font-awesome", 
                                                "5.13.0", "./shared/fontawesome", 
                                                stylesheet = c("css/all.min.css"))
  }
  htmltools::browsable(iconTag)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked a year ago, but in case anyone else is looking for an answer: there is a module [rstudio/fontawesome](https://rdrr.io/github/rstudio/fontawesome/man/fa_i.html) for this. The `shiny::icon()` implementation uses `fa_i()` internally, but if you call `fa_i()` yourself you should be able to add the "pro" icons using the "`html_dependency`" argument. From the docs, the argument:

> Provides an opportunity to use a custom `html_dependency` object (created via a call to `htmltools::htmlDependency()`) instead of one supplied by the function (which uses Font Awesome's free assets and are bundled in the package). **A custom `html_dependency` object is useful when you have paid icons from Font Awesome** or would otherwise like to customize exactly which icon assets are used (e.g., woff, woff2, eot, etc.). By default, this is `NULL` where the function internally generates an `html_dependency`.